# best option to sort edges in kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, heap, quicksort, kruskals-algorithm

I'm implementing Kruskal's algorithm and i'm not sure what is better way to order edges. 
I need best time complexity for big inputs(300 000+ edges).
I know they are similar in time complexity, but i'd like to know which is faster for big inputs.

Comment: Start with using the library-supplied sort function. Get your solution working.  It might very well be fast enough. If it isn't, then profile and decide whether it's the sort or something else that's causing the slow-down. Note, however, that unless you're really good at optimizing code, your custom sort is likely to be slower than the built-in version.

Comment: I used library qsort() in c and it was enough. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with using the library-supplied sort function. Get your solution working. It might very well be fast enough. If it isn't, then profile and decide whether it's the sort or something else that's causing the slow-down. Note, however, that unless you're really good at optimizing code, your custom sort is likely to be slower than the built-in version.